# Teradata set table

Tags: teradata, informatica

I have a set table in teradata , when I load duplicate records throough informatica , session fails because it tries to push duplicate records in SET table.

I want that whenever duplicate records being loaded informatica rejects them using TPT or Relation connection

can anyone help me with properties I need to set

Comment: What operator are you using with TPT or Relation to load the data?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to keep track of what records are rejected due to duplication in the TPT logs? It seems like you are open to suggestions about TPT or relational connections, so I assume you don't really care about TPT level logs.

If this assumption is correct then you can simply put an Aggregator Transformation in the mapping and mark every field as Group By. As expected, this will add a group by clause in the generated query and eliminate duplicates in the source data.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following things:
1. If you'll use fload or TPT Fast load then the utility will implicitly remove the duplicates but this utility can only be used for loading into empty tables.
2. If you are trying to load data in non-empty table then place a sorter and de-dupe your data in Informatica 
3. Also try changing the flag stop on error to 0 and flag Error limit in target to -1
Please share your results with us.